# Return rolling 12 months of current (string) month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table. I only want to return the past 12 months of the current month. How can this happen?

```
 ID    Month   
 1     201803
 2     201804
 3     201704
 4     201706
```

Expected output: (Past 12 Months of lastest month listed)

```
 ID    Month   
 1     201803
 2     201804
 3     201704
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `201706` in result and not `201704` ?

Comment: What is the data type of `Month'?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Month` is a string, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.Month = to_char(sysdate - interval '11' month, 'YYYYMM');
```

If you want this based on the latest month in the data, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(Month) over () as max_month
      from t
     ) t
where month >= to_char(to_date(max_month, 'YYYYMM') - interval '11' month, 'YYYYMM');
```

The `11` is because the latest month is also included in the result set.

Answer (score -2):

This should also work.

`Select ID, Month
From Table
Where max(left(month,4) = left(Month,4)
      OR (max(left(month,4) = left(Month,4) - 1
          AND right(max(month),2) <= right(month,2))`